# How to write Linq for group by time period and count calculation by this period

Tags: linq, group-by, .net-6.0

The following model contains the name of the airport and the dates of arrival flights:

```
public class FlightStatisticsModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Airport name
    /// </summary>
    public string AirportTitle { get; init; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Arrival datetime
    /// </summary>
    public List<DateTime> ArrivalTime { get; set; }
```

}

I want to populate the following DTO:

```
public class ArrivalFlightsDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Airport name
    /// </summary>
    public string AirportTitle { get; init; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Arrival count
    /// </summary>
    public int ArrivalCount { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// From date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// To date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

methods that populate DTO contains folloving logic

```
private static List<ArrivalFlightsDto> GroupByPeriod(FlightStatisticsModel flightStatisticsModel, DateTime date, int period)
{
    var list = new List<DateRange>();

    for (var dt = date; dt <= date.AddDays(1); dt = dt.AddMinutes(period))
    {
        if (dt.AddMinutes(period) > date.AddDays(1))
        {
            list.Add(new DateRange { from = dt, to = date.AddDays(1) });
            break;
        }
        list.Add(new DateRange{ from = dt, to = dt.AddMinutes(period)});
    }

    return list.Select(item => new ArrivalFlightsDto
    {
        AirportTitle = flightStatisticsModel.AirportTitle, 
        From = item.from, 
        To = item.to, 
        ArrivalCount = flightStatisticsModel.ArrivalTime.Count(t => t >= item.from && t <= item.to)
    }).ToList();
}
```

In this case, this method creates a list of date ranges by minute periods for a 24 hourses. From 00:00 to 24:00. After that, ArrivalFlightsDto is populated. For example if pass period = 30 it return:

Airport,from,to,count

name,   00:00:00,   00:30:00,   6

name,   00:30:00,   01:00:00,   4

name,   01:00:00,   01:30:00,   6

I could wrote single sql that would replace this method... but can anyone help or give me an idea how to get rid of the loop and range population by refactoring this method it into a single LINQ query? Thanks.